# Persisting Large Data in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an Android application that queries a web service asynchronously for what could potentially be a  good sized amount of data - more than I would want to store in SharedPreferences.  Initially, I was thinking of just running the query each time, but the more I work with it, the clunkier that feels.  So, what is the best way to store this data and still refresh it regularly?

I was thinking of a SQLite database, but maybe there's an easier way?  I don't really need a full database, but I will be storing several events and their corresponding data.

Also, if I use the database, what's the best way to periodically update it?

Comment: See [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: What kind of data do you get from server? Jsons? Images?

Comment: It's JSON data, no images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say using a database here is perfectly fine.

Considering periodic updates you can have various strategies:

1. Check for updates at startup/when user enters the relevant screen. Can be quite fast if you use something like ETag.
2. Do a scheduled update every hour/day/week. Can be implemented with something like the `SyncAdapter`
3. Let the server tell you when the data has changed using a push notification and then update the data. Maybe with some small random delay so not all clients will do the request to the server at the same time.

Depending on whether you control the server or not and how important it is that the data is always up to date, pick the one that suits your needs the best or use a combination.

Answer (score 2):

this is an sq-`LITE` db, so it's not a full-blown Oracle cluster :).

The amount of work, which should be done in order to initialize your app's database and give it a go is pretty small and is encapsulated in a single class like:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public DatabaseHelper( Context ctx ) {
    super( ctx, "myapp.db", null, 1 );
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db ) {
    db.execSQL( 
      "CREATE TABLE location ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, lat REAL NOT NULL, lon REAL NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, locality TEXT NOT NULL,"
                              + " UNIQUE( name ) ON CONFLICT REPLACE );" );
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) {}
}
```

another option would be to use a `web-clinet` DB, which is usually the case with phonegap/cordova-powered apps.

as to updates, @joris described them pretty well